# SQL Join condition clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database with as diagram shows (see picture below)
[image]

My task is to show total value of orders handled by each Employees.
I have SQL statement:

```
SELECT e.FirstName,
       e.LastName,
       SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1-od.Discount)) 
FROM Orders AS o
JOIN Employees AS e
ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
JOIN [Order Details] AS od
ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY e.FirstName,e.LastName
```

I have problem with further steps. I need to limited results only for those employees which:

- A) Have employees under them
- B) Don't have any employees under them

I know It concern field ReportsTO in Employees table, but I don't know how get proper SQL clause. I am supposed to do with "EXISTS" or self-join ?

Thank You.

Comment: Your key is the 1st word in A and 2nd word in b. its SQL Keyword HAVING :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Just use Exists.

```
  Where Exists(Select 1 from Employees where ReportsTo = e.EmployeeId)
```

Comment: This works if there is only 1 level of reporting. If you have multiple layers of people (Sam reports to Janet who reports to Amit who reports to Trevor), this query is only getting the orders for Amit when you query for Trevor's reports.

Comment: But that is all he needed.  He didnt need to know if there were multiple levels.  He just needed to know if the person had anybody reporting to them.

Comment: If you need to recurse the levels you could use a CTE and Union ALL

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join to try to find someone reporting to him

```
SELECT e.FirstName,
       e.LastName,
       SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1-od.Discount)) 
FROM Orders AS o
INNER JOIN Employees AS e    
   ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN Employees as under  -- self join
   ON e.EmployeeID = under.ReportTo
INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS od
   ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY e.FirstName,e.LastName

HAVING MAX(under.ReportTo) IS NULL     -- If doesnt find a match mean no one subordinate
   -- MAX(under.ReportTo) IS NOT NULL  -- mean have at least one subordinate
```

Comment: Thank You for replay, but unfortunately statement works only for for:
MAX(under.ReportTo) IS NOT NULL, MAX(under.ReportTo) IS NULL returns no results. @Dobbins statement below works fine, solving problem with Exists condition

Comment: I swap the `LEFT` and `INNER` join, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

With a self join you can potentially create  duplicates which would be difficult to debug due to the `GROUP BY`. `EXISTS` with a correlated sub query in the `WHERE` clause would be how I would accomplish this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees e
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Employees _e 
  WHERE _e.ReportsTo = e.EmployeeID)
```

In your query:

```
SELECT e.FirstName,
       e.LastName,
       SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1-od.Discount)) 
FROM Orders AS o
JOIN Employees AS e
ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
JOIN [Order Details] AS od
ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
WHERE /*NOT*/ EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Employees _e 
  WHERE _e.ReportsTo = e.EmployeeID)
GROUP BY e.FirstName,e.LastName
```